# How to change the Checkbox icon to behave like **indeterminate** with "+" and "-" Symbols

Tags: javascript, html, css

**I have checkbox with its original behaviour. I wanted to add + and - symbols to it while expanding and collapsing those checkbox.**

Can any one please tell me how can I achieve this ?

Following is my Code in jade:

```
.form-group
  .checkbox#some-checkbox(style="margin-left: 10px;")
    label(data-toggle='collapse', data-target='#collapseOne', aria-expanded='false', aria-controls='collapseOne')
      input(type='checkbox')
      |  My Name
#collapseOne.collapse(aria-expanded='false')
  .well1
    .row    
      .col-sm-12.col-lg-12
        .nutrition-category
          .row.header3.margin-left-10
              .row.paragraph
                .col-xs-6(style="font-size: 18px;")  New Name
```

Non Jade (HTML) Code:

```
<div class="form-group">
 <div class="checkbox" id="some-checkbox" style="margin-left: 10px">
 <label data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-
   expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
   <input type="checkbox"/> My Name
 </label>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="collapse" id="collapseOne" aria-expanded="false">
  <div class="well1">
    <div class="row">   
     <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
      <div class="nutrition-category">
       <div class="row header3 margin-left-10">
        <div class="row paragraph">
          <div class="col-xs-6" style="font-size: 18px"> New 
          Name</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

and here is the javascript that i have used for it:

```
script(type='text/javascript').
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#some-checkbox").prop("indeterminate", true);
});
```

Comment: Can you add the non-jade HTML?

Comment: I have added the non jade html code. Could you please help me ?

Comment: So what issue are you actually having when trying to implement this feature?

Comment: checkbox should display with the + and - symbols where as it is displaying with normal tick mark.

Comment: Checkbox can only display a "tick". You can style the label however you like, and then hide the checkbox [accessibly](https://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/hiding-content-for-accessibility).